# In Embedded Programming, are we dealing with Virtual address and Physical address?

Tags: c, embedded

From Datasheet of a hardware chip,

```
Peripherals (at physical address 0x20000000 on) are mapped into the kernel virtual 
address

 space starting at address 0xF2000000. Thus a peripheral advertised here at bus address 
0x7Ennnnnn is available in the ARM kenel at virtual address 0xF2nnnnnn.
```

Then from the Sample code,

```
  #define BCM2835_PERI_BASE          0x20000000
```

I thought Programmer are supposed to dealing with Virtual address, the Physical address is hiding behind. The MMU hides the smaller side of physical address and makes the virtual address bigger. The end user/Programmer would dealing with virtual address.

But from above, the sample code clearly used the physical address instead, why?

Sample code

```
     #define BCM2835_PERI_BASE           0x20000000
    #define GPIO_PADS       (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x00100000)
    #define CLOCK_BASE      (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x00101000)
    #define GPIO_BASE       (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x00200000)
    #define GPIO_TIMER      (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x0000B000)
    #define GPIO_PWM        (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x0020C000)

   static volatile uint32_t *pads ;



 if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_CLOEXEC) ) < 0)
return wiringPiFailure (WPI_ALMOST, "wiringPiSetup: Unable to open /dev/mem: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;

       pads = (uint32_t *)mmap(0, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, GPIO_PADS) ;
```

Comment: Could you reference which hardware chip, or a link to the context from which this was found?

Comment: Broadcom 2835 ARM Peripheral datasheet.  I am just asking are we suppose to use physical or virtual address, this applies to all hardware chip, not just broadcom's

Comment: Is this code running in the ARM kernel? If not then the above statement doesn't apply.

Comment: @arms, Yes, it's running ARM kernel.

Comment: Depends. If some OS with Memory management (like Linux) is being used, then virtual address should be used by the programmer. Otherwise, directly physical address should be used by programmer.

Comment: @Ghosh, well, your statement contradict with Broadcom's sample code. It has MMU(memory management), but it used physical address instead.

Comment: @lilzz: It is my 'generic' understanding. Could you share some more code sample (from .c file, not header) where some address is being read/written?

Comment: @Ghosh, I don't u can get anything from .c section but here u go void setPadDrive (int group, int value)
{
  uint32_t wrVal ;

  if ((wiringPiMode == WPI_MODE_PINS) || (wiringPiMode == WPI_MODE_PHYS) || (wiringPiMode == WPI_MODE_GPIO))
  {
    if ((group < 0) || (group > 2))
      return ;

    wrVal = BCM_PASSWORD | 0x18 | (value & 7) ;
    *(pads + group + 11) = wrVal ;

Comment: The reference to the physical address may be important *before* the MMU is configured. Or it may be an important part *of configuring* the MMU.  Or perhaps the code is written with the hardware addresses in mind (since those are in the data sheet), and some macro is used to inverse-map those to the virtual addresses wherever an address is actually used.  Or perhaps the MMU actually gets configured so that for this range virtual=physical.  Generally speaking, embedded systems work is more hardware-aware, so not everything gets abstracted in thinking (though that's also true of *driver* work)

Comment: @Chris,   I check the code,mmap function is that relates to MMU? it takes a physical address and is that relate to your statement?

Comment: Possibly, it's in the *offset* field of the call.  What "device" does the fd point to?  Something comparable to /dev/mem on linux?

Comment: @Chris, yeah,u r right. it points to /dev/mem.    So in linux every pierce of hardware can be referenced as /dev/**** ?

Comment: No, only those which the kernel has code to present in this way, and for which a device node with corresponding major and minor numbers has been created on the file system.  But /dev/mem seems to be a way to map any part of the physical address space, potentially including special function registers of on-chip peripherals.  By all appearances the code you are talking about is making the "needs the physical address to configure mapping" usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is true that a kernel developer works in virtual memory, the developer still needs to worry about physical memory.

The device that you have has a GPIO controller at physical address GPIO_PADS. You want to program the GPIO for which you need to get access to its memory.

The code that you have show calls `mmap` to take the physical address in GPIO_PADS and gets the MMU to map this into your virtual address space. You now can read and write to the memory directly and do the GPIO programming that you need.